# How to resolve this issue of animate.css

Tags: angular

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\My work\angular\node_modules\animate.css\animate.css' in 'D:\My work\angular\biker-zone'

Comment: Check your provided path. There is some  mistake.

Comment: @import '../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css'; I have written this line in style.css which is inside scss dir, but still same error

Comment: Also used this @import '~animate.css/animate.css';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
Try to add this line

```
"node_modules/animate.css/animate.css"
```

in your style array of angular.json file 
like bellow

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
        ]
```